# Bitmap to jpeg without saving to the file system

Tags: android, bitmap

How to compress bitmap to jpeg? Storing in a file system is unacceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use below code!

```
Bitmap bmp = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```